# bigquery sql table function with string interpolation

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, pivot, prepared-statement, table-functions

I am trying to write a BigQuery SQL function / stored procedure / table function that accepts as input:

- a `INT64` filter for the `WHERE` clause,
- a table name (`STRING` type) as fully qualified name e.g. `project_id.dataset_name.table_name`

The idea is to dynamically figure out the table name and provide a filter to slice the data to return as a table.

However if try to write a Table Function (TVF) and I use `SET` to start dynamically writing the SQL to execute, then I see this error:

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword SET at [4:5]
```

If I try to write a stored procedure, then it expects `BEGIN` and `END` and throws this error:

```
Syntax error: Expected keyword BEGIN or keyword LANGUAGE but got keyword AS at [3:1]
```

If I try to add those, then I get various validation errors basically because I need to remove the `WITH` using CTEs (Common Table Expression), and semicolons `;` etc.

But what I am really trying to do is using a **table function**:

1. to combine some CTEs dynamically with those inputs above (e.g. the input table name),
2. to `PIVOT` that data,
3. to then eventually return a table as a result of a `SELECT`.

A bit like producing a View that could be used in other SQL queries, but without creating the view (because the slice of data can be decided dynamically with the other `INT64` input filter).

Once I dynamically build the SQL string I would like to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` that SQL and provide a `SELECT` as a final step of the table function to return the "dynamic table".

The thing is that:

- I don't know before runtime the name of this table.
- But I have all these tables with the same structure, so the SQL should apply to all of them.

Is this possible at all?

This is the not-so-working SQL I am trying to work around. See what I am trying to inject with `%s` and `num_days`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION `my_dataset.my_table_func_name`(num_days INT64, fqn_org_table STRING)
AS (
    -- this SET breaks !!!

    SET f_query = """
    WITH report_cst_t AS (
        SELECT
            DATE(start) as day,
            entity_id,
            conn_sub_type,
        FROM `%s` AS oa
        CROSS JOIN UNNEST(oa.connection_sub_type) AS conn_sub_type
        WHERE
            DATE(start) > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL num_days DAY)
            AND oa.entity_id IN ('my-very-long-id')
        ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
    ),
    cst AS (
        SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT day, entity_id, report_cst_t FROM report_cst_t)
            PIVOT (COUNT(*) AS connection_sub_type FOR report_cst_t.conn_sub_type IN ('cat1', 'cat2','cat3' ))
    )
    """;

    -- here I would like to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE !!!

    SELECT
            cst.day,
            cst.entity_id,
            cst.connection_sub_type_cat1 AS cst_cat1,
            cst.connection_sub_type_cat2 AS cst_cat2,
            cst.connection_sub_type_cat3 AS cst_cat3,
    FROM cst
    ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be satisfying but since [Procedural language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language) or [DDL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language) are not allowed inside [Table functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions) currently, one possible way around would be simply using `PROCEDURE` like below.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_dataset.temp_procedure(filter_value INT64, table_name STRING)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT(CONCAT(
        "SELECT year, COUNT(1) as record_count, ",
        "FROM %s                                ",
        "WHERE year = %d                        ",
        "GROUP BY year                          ",
        ";                                      "
    ), table_name, filter_value);
END;

CALL my_dataset.temp_procedure(2002, 'bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current');
```